# Segmentation fault in odd/even recursive function

Tags: c, recursion, segmentation-fault

I wrote the following code in order to find whether a number is even or odd using a recursive function.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int posneg(int n){ 
    
    if (posneg(n-1)%2 == 0){
        return 1;
    }
    else {
        return 0;
    }
}

main () { 
    int num;
    
    do{ 
        printf("Provide a number"); 
        scanf("%d",&num); 
    } while (num <= 0);
    if (posneg(num) == 1)
        printf("The number is even");
    else 
        printf("The number is odd");

}
```

The code compiles successfully but I get a Segmentation Fault.

Any ideas what is the cause of that?

Comment: When will the recursion of your posneg function stop?

Comment: "posneg" means even or odd? Fascinating.

Comment: When the number is either odd or even

Comment: The integer is always either odd or even, so you're saying the posneg function will never recurse?

Comment: Try tracing through the logic by hand. You'll see it never stops. You need to test `n` *before* the recursive call.

Comment: Let's try it a slightly different way: what code in your function prevents any call to `posneg()` from recursing?

Comment: What's the point of the `%2`? Posneg can only return 0 or 1, and anyway if you have `%2` available, you don't need the recursion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A function to determine whether a number is even or odd is  a poor candidate to implement recursively, unless the goal is to illustrate that oftentimes recursion is not an ideal solution.

A recursive solution must have a base case, otherwise it will continue calling itself until the system runs out of resources and the program crashes.

How can we determine if a number is even or odd recursively? One way is to gradually add or subtract two from the number until we get to -1, 0, or 1 (our base cases):

```
// Let's say a return value of '1' means odd and '0' means even
int evenodd (int n)
{
    if(-1 == n || 1 == n) // base case: n is odd
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else if(0 == n) // base case: n is even
    {
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        return evenodd(n > 0 ? n-2 : n+2);
    }
}
```

Comment: @ikegami it leads to UB when n == INT_MIN. Bad idea.

Comment: 0___________, ok, `if (n > 0) n = -n;` then :) But that feels weird.

Answer (score 0):

You're getting a segmentation fault because you're code is causing a **stack overflow**.

```c
int posneg(int n){ 
        
    if (posneg(n-1)%2 == 0){
        return 1;
    }
    else {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Every time a recursive function calls itself, a new activation record is added to the stack containing the arguments of the new call.

This recursive function will never evaluate to the base case because it has to determine whether it's divisible by 2, and in order to do that, you have to call the function to evaluate it. This is repeated until your program runs out of stack.

Answer (score 0):

For starters according to the C Standard the function main without parameters shall be declared like

```
int main( void )
```

You may not omit the return type of the function.

Secondly there is no great sense to declare the variable `num` as having the type `int` if you expect a non-negative number. The variable should be declared as having the type `unsigned int`.

The function produces an infinite recursion due to the if statement inside the function

```
int posneg(int n){ 
    
    if (posneg(n-1)%2 == 0){
        return 1;
    }
    else {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Using your approach of defining the function it can look for example the following way as it is shown in the demonstrative program below

```
#include <stdio.h>

int posneg( unsigned int n )
{ 
    return ( n == 0 ) || ( ( 1 + posneg( n - 1 ) ) % 2 );
}

int main( void )
{
    while ( 1 )
    {
        printf( "Provide a non-negative number (0 - exit): " );
        
        unsigned int n;
        
        if ( scanf( "%u", &n ) != 1 || n == 0 ) break;
        
        if ( posneg( n ))
        {
            printf( "The number %u is even.\n", n );
        }           
        else
        {
            printf( "The number %u is odd.\n", n );
        }
            
    }
}
```

the program output might look like

```
Provide a non-negative number (0 - exit): 1
The number 1 is odd.
Provide a non-negative number (0 - exit): 2
The number 2 is even.
Provide a non-negative number (0 - exit): 3
The number 3 is odd.
Provide a non-negative number (0 - exit): 4
The number 4 is even.
Provide a non-negative number (0 - exit): 5
The number 5 is odd.
Provide a non-negative number (0 - exit): 6
The number 6 is even.
Provide a non-negative number (0 - exit): 7
The number 7 is odd.
Provide a non-negative number (0 - exit): 8
The number 8 is even.
Provide a non-negative number (0 - exit): 9
The number 9 is odd.
Provide a non-negative number (0 - exit): 0
```